# Java and Javascript getTime give different values

Tags: javascript, java

I need to compare dates. One date is gotten from JWT and the other is gotten from Javascript getTime(). But the 2 dates that should bre relatively close have a differents of X1000.

Javascript getTime() -> 1553001077175
Java JWT expiration ->  1553087477

I get the expiration from JWT by doing the base64 conversion.

JWT expiration is calculated as follows:

```
long now = (new Date()).getTime();
        Date validity;
        validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds);
```

And then butten into JWT like so:

```
Jwts.builder()....setExpration(validity).compact()
```

Why is the difference so large?

Comment: Different timezones between client and server? Someone forgot to set DST on server? `console.log(new Date(1553001077175), new Date(1553087477000))`

Comment: It looks like somewhere in the compacting, sending and decoding the final 3 numbers get lost.

Comment: Java unix timestamp is likely in seconds

Comment: I dug into the JWTS libary. and in the bowels i discovered that it does getTime() / 1000L. I wish i could have found some documentations aobut it....

Comment: @mplungjan apparantley i used wrong keywords for search.